# Qt Creator is not displaying SFML windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, runtime-error, sfml

I've recently set up qt creator to work with SFML, and I tried running a piece of code as a test to see if it works. I must note the code bellow **works perfectly** in Codeblocks IDE but in qt creator it simply displays a console with the text "Press RETURN to close this window..."

```
  #include <SFML/System.hpp>
  #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
  #include <iostream> 

 using namespace std;
 using namespace sf;

  Window w(VideoMode(350,350,32), "Tic Tac Toe"); Event e1; const Input&
  in1 = w.GetInput();

  int main() {
      while(w.IsOpened())
      {
          w.Display();
      }
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Here is my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\SFML-1.6\include
LIBS += C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-system.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-window.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-graphics.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-audio.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-network.lib
```

Never in a million years did I imagine working with SFML on my favorite IDE is so difficult, what is the problem?

Comment: You have `CONFIG += console` in your `pro`

Comment: No, must I add CONFIG -= gui?