# Qt Creator not displaying SFML windows

Tags: c++, qt-creator, sfml

I've recently set up qt creator to work with SFML, and I tried running a piece of code as a test to see if it works. I must note the code bellow **works perfectly** in Codeblocks IDE but in qt creator it simply displays a console with the text "Press RETURN to close this window..."

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

Window w(VideoMode(350,350,32), "Tic Tac Toe"); Event e1; const Input&
in1 = w.GetInput();

int main() {
    while(w.IsOpened())
    {
        w.Display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\SFML-1.6\include
LIBS += C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-system.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-window.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-graphics.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-audio.lib \
    C:\SFML-1.6\lib\sfml-network.lib
```

Never in a million years did I imagine working with SFML on my favorite IDE is so difficult, what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window not displaying issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132218/window-not-displaying-issue)

Comment: @Mankarse, I'm not getting my question answered, nor do I have rep to start a bounty, I've been struggling to get this working for more than 2 weeks :(

Comment: try to change backslashes onto slashes in LIBS & INCLUDEPATH

Comment: @Jupiter that gives me errors, and tells me it cannot find the lib

Comment: @Jupiter after fixing a minor thing, I didn't get any errors but this time it was the same thing as before, no window was rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use global object. They might mess up with SFML's internal.

Also you should process events. Not doing so might be the reason of your issue.

Try [the example](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/sources/window-events.cpp) from [the tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-events.php).

If you're discovering SFML for the first time I strongly suggest you start with 2.0 instead of the old, buggy and deprecated 1.6 version. Have a look at some discussions on the official forum to understand why 2.0 is better although it is currently "only" a release candidate.